# Hiding address bar on mobile when scrolling child with overflow: auto

Tags: css, mobile, scroll

When you create a long basic page and scroll it, most mobile browsers do something automatically with the address bar. For example on android chrome, as you scroll down the address bar disappears with the scroll.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect if you are not scrolling the body? For example, if you had a child div that contained the content with a `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the address bar on iPhone you can use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimal-ui">
```

There is no such easy solution for Android such as the one for iOS 7 on iPhone with just meta a tag.

You can try this snippet from Scott Jehl to hide the bar in js targeting both iOS and Android.

```
/*! Normalized address bar hiding for iOS & Android (c) @scottjehl MIT License */
(function( win ){
    var doc = win.document;

    // If there's a hash, or addEventListener is undefined, stop here
    if(!win.navigator.standalone && !location.hash && win.addEventListener ){

        //scroll to 1
        win.scrollTo( 0, 1 );
        var scrollTop = 1,
            getScrollTop = function(){
                return win.pageYOffset || doc.compatMode === "CSS1Compat" && doc.documentElement.scrollTop || doc.body.scrollTop || 0;
            },

            //reset to 0 on bodyready, if needed
            bodycheck = setInterval(function(){
                if( doc.body ){
                    clearInterval( bodycheck );
                    scrollTop = getScrollTop();
                    win.scrollTo( 0, scrollTop === 1 ? 0 : 1 );
                }   
            }, 15 );

        win.addEventListener( "load", function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                //at load, if user hasn't scrolled more than 20 or so...
                if( getScrollTop() < 20 ){
                    //reset to hide addr bar at onload
                    win.scrollTo( 0, scrollTop === 1 ? 0 : 1 );
                }
            }, 0);
        }, false );
    }
})( this );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to remove the address bar all together. Just trying to replicate the usual functionality of scrolling body with a scrolling child.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I will see if I can edit my answer as soon as I have some time.